# Elastic search exact Match phrase not having extra characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running into an issue, not able to move ahead with a unique problem.
I have few documents having following data:

```
"A 123"
"B 123"
"A 123 ABC"
"A 123"
"A 234"
"A 123 XYZ"
```

Now what I am trying to use match phrase only for "A 123", but the match phrase query is returning me the not 2 result but 4 result

```
"A 123", "A 123 ABC", "A 123", "A 123 XYZ"
```

My problem is i don't need those values which has extra text other than `"A 123"`.

The match phrase is always returning the above said.

Please suggest what i am missing here.

regards
abhi

Comment: Share your query

Comment: For exact matches use a [`term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "message" : {
                "query" : "A 123",
                "operator" : "and" // use this incase matching whole stirng not in terms separate by spaces 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I am new to this elastic search and using bool quires using Java api to build query. How i can translate the above said query in bool query. The following query I am using as of now.

Comment: QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("fieldName", "A 123")